# how to assign conga composer button to particular user/profile?

Tags: custom-button, conga, conga-composer

I have one pdf formate conga composer button that button only can see a read-only profile and another button default formate conga composer button assign some particular user how?

Answer (score 0):

you need two profiles two record type and two layouts. After you assign a profile to a user assign Record type to the profile and the update the buttons on related page layout as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer from Conga:
https://support.conga.com/content/composer/composer-parameter-guide/dc

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.